# Cómo puedo utilizar un mismo screen para diferentes tabs de un Top Tab Navigator en React Native?

Tags: react-native

Estoy intentando filtrar datos desde firebase y en cada Tab pretendo utilizar el mismo screen que contiene una lista (Flatlist) para mostrar los datos. El parámetro para filtrar lo recibe el screen para entregarlo luego al api que filtra en la BD. La cuestión es que el Tab.Navigator carga todos los filtros, uno tras otro, y hace que todos los tabs tengan el mismo valor, o sea, el de la última consulta que se ejecutó, Ej:(Tab A, B, C muestran resultado de filtro correspondiente a C). No obstante, cuando hago refresh en cada tab, este muestra el resultado que le corresponde pero actualiza los demas tabs con este resultado Ej: (refresh en Tab B hace que Tab A, C muestran resultado correspondiente a B).

Comment: Hola Gustavo, quizá no puedo comprender bien qué funcionamiento esperas que ocurra, y menos si no añades algún fragmento de código a la pregunta para que podamos darnos a una idea de lo que posiblemente puede ocurrir.  Lo que te puedo decir es que de acuerdo al plugin que utilices para la navegación, puede ser react-native-navigation tiende a renderizar cada pantalla de un tabbar cuando este se inicializa, no cuando lo estás viendo, por lo que puede ser la razón del comportamiento que ves

Comment: Muchas gracias @GermanAlzate por tu comentario. Tienes razón, debí haber puesto el código. Pues el problema lo resolví por otra vía ya que me no logré hacerlo con navigation. Nada, quería usar un mismo screen ya que en cada tab la estructura era la misma, pero los datos variaban según un valor para filtrar.

Comment: Quería hacer: `<Tab.Navigator ... }}>   <Tab.Screen name="Tab1" component=MyScreen} initialParams={{filter: 'filter_value'}}   />`...Funcionaba "bien" pero cuando terminaba el load todos los tabs tenian el ultimo resultado filtrado. Al hacer refresh en cada tab, mostraba los resultados correctos pero todos los demas se actualizaban con este. Soy nuevo en RN, quizás me pasé por alto alguna técnica para conservarr los states en esatas condiciones. Nada, hice el "tab naivgator" con un flatlist horizontal y listo. No obstante, quisiera llegar a una solución para lo anterior. Saludos y respetos